# Can't Call requireActivity() From ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin

I am unable to call requireActivity() from inside a RecyclerView.ViewHolder that is defined inside of my Fragment class:

```
class ActFrag: Fragment() {
    ...
    class ActHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        ...
        var mActivity = requireActivity() // requireActivity() is not in scope.
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

...
}

It works in my Java files, but now that I am working in Kotlin, it doesn't seem to want to play ball. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

By default, nested classes are static (i.e., they don't have a reference to the containing outer class). You can add the `inner` keyword to make them an inner class, which would allow you to call methods on the outer class:

```
inner class ActHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
```

Comment: Kotlin has made some annoying changes. (I guess necessary) Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yeah, the Java's approach of adding `static` to remove the 'inner'-ness of a nested class feels odd once you get used to Kotlin's more natural approach of adding `inner` only when you explicitly want to make a nested class into an inner class. Clearly just two sides of the same coin though.